# JVM crashes when running Spring Boot web app

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, jvm

My Spring boot 2.0.3 web app runs fine on Eclipse, with Java 1.8-1.4.1 and the embedded Tomcat.  But when I build my war file (using mvn package) and deploy it to linux  (uname -mrs gives Linux 4.9.77-31.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64), and run it (  same java version) on a external Tomcat 9.0.10, the JVM crashes when it connects to Oracle. The code where the crash occurs is:

```
@Repository
public class ReadFromDb {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;

    public TspsPatent readTspsPatent(TspsPatent tspsPatent)
    {
        System.out.println("DSxxx1");   

        // Next line crashes
        List<TspsPatent> tspsPatents = jdbcTemplate.query("select 3 patent_sk from dual",
                (rs, rowNum) -> new TspsPatent (rs.getString("patent_sk")));

        System.out.println("DSxxx2"); 
        if (tspsPatents.size() == 0) {return null;}
        return tspsPatents.get(0);
    }
}
```

ie the DSxxx1 line is printed in catalina.out, but DSxxx2 isn't.
The full catalina.out is here:

[catalina.out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wsZDKdrjR4f--_1faTKa7Sxe0eROF2Qv)

If examine the jni connections using:

```
-Xcheck:jni
```

in setenv.sh, then in catalina.out I get:
[catalina-jni.out](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NYpL7EPbbeoDTEwzSsn8dUKqPFFSJk9P)

When the JVM crashes it creates a log file `hs_err_pid40342.log`, which is here:

[hs_err_pid40342.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T7crkwB4lT9W8qJycaAa0qFnBc5t23UK)

This log file contains , on lines 508 - 518 a group of `java/lang/ClassNotFoundException` one of which is:

```
Event: 18.567 Thread 0x00007fe844620000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/clarivate/dataviewer/model/TspsPatentCustomizer> (0x000000059e3dd210) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u141/9370/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
```

I wrote the package: 
com/clarivate/dataviewer/model
but there is no class called TspsPatentCustomizer
I have 2 classes with similar names in this package:
TspsPatent and TspsPatentNumberChange
but they are both just plain pojo's.
Why is the JVM looking for a class called TspsPatentCustomizer when this class has never existed?

The NamedParameterJdbcTemplate class handles the dB connections. It is in :

```
spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar
```

and this jar is in my war file

My `application.properties` has:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
server.port=8090    
server.servlet.path=/

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:oci:@myDataBase

spring.datasource.username=myUser
spring.datasource.password=myPassword

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

My `pom.xml` file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.clarivate</groupId>
<artifactId>dataviewer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>DataViewer</name> 

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>


    <!-- DS may need to remove for tomcat installation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>  
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

   <!-- Required to find ojdbc6, because Oracle don't make it available to maven-->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>codelds</id>
          <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>DataViewer</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <configuration>
                <!--  <mainClass>com.clarivate.dataviewer.DvMain</mainClass>-->
                  <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>


<description>TSPS data viewer</description>
```

One query is this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

My `$ORACLE_HOME` is not part of my war file, it's on linux at:
`/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1`

which can't be changed.
So the version numbers are slightly different, does this make a difference and if so how do I change my maven version?
The strange TspsPatentConversion reference is a sideline, my main concern is to get the app running. Have I missed out any Oracle related settings or dependencies?
Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: try `mvn clean package`

Comment: Try to search for references to TspsPatentCustomizer somewhere in your project.

Comment: @sidgate i've done plenty mvn clean's

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy i've done find . -type f -exec grep -il TspsPatentConversion {} \; and find . -name  "*TspsPatentConversion*", nothing is returned (with * before and after TspsPatentConversion)

Comment: I doubt Maven is inventing that name, so it has to come from somewhere... Try to look at environment variables or in the Tomcat configuration

Comment: @Alexis_Dufrenoy I agree, but i've just tried env | grep -i conversion and i've ran the 2 find's above in $CATALINA_HOME and nothing

Comment: A missing class should not lead to a dump. I would say the crash happens in libocijdbc11.so. I guess the versions must match or the lib has a bug.

Comment: @andi Why do you think that? libocijdbc11.so is not in my war file, it's at $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libocijdbc11.so and is used by all other applications so it's unlikely to be corrupt.

Comment: You have other java applications running on that server connecting via the same OCI jdbc Driver? Then it should be ok. Look at line 93+95 of the log. The lib is called via JNI and itself calls libjvm.so, where the SIGSEGV occurs. Refs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212659 (which is likely your ticket)

Comment: @andi Yes, i've had a look at line 93-95. I added export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xcheck:jni" into setenv.sh to show any jni errors, i've updated the question with the new catalina.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was slightly mismatched version in the Oracle client see:
[Oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2553773?start=0&tstart=0)

In my war file I had ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar, my Oracle client in $ORACLE_HOME on Linux was 11.2.0, these 2 versions are not identical and this incompatability caused the jvm crash. The solution was to remove ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar from the war to force  my app to use ojdbc6.jar in $ORACLE_HOME. To do this you add ojdbc6 scope "provided" to the pom.